# Why NSUTF8StringEncoding can be directly used in the call without import it

Tags: objective-c

Am new to objective-c and am reading the code https://github.com/zhangxigithub/ZXTools/blob/master/Class/ZXAES/NSData%2BZXAES.m.

I cannot understand the following line:

```
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I know that NSUTF8StringEncoding is defined in the NSString.h, but it is not imported here. So why this enum type can be directly used? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much everything having to do with all the "NS" and "UI" classes is imported by default.

Comment: @HotLicks More specifically they are typically imported via the pch file generated for the typical Xcode project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation contains NSString.h and its like and Foundation.h is imported, usually in AppName-Prefix.pch. The .pch file stands for precompiled headers and is specified in the app Xcode build Build Settings. the .pch file is implicitly imported by the project code files.

In an iOS project the pch file typically contains the following with possible additions such as CoreData:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Does this mean that we can omit importing foundation.h explicitly?

Comment: Basically yes. But it is generally not a good idea to put lots of include files in the pch file.